# How can I build routing into a SPA jQuery app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, routes

I am building a simple MVP of an idea in jQuery and Rails 5. I would like to avoid introducing a front end framework for the purposes of the simple project.

In order to let users navigate with the forward/back button I made different templates with "routes" such as `/profile` and `/network` as follows.

I use popstate to change which handlebars template I render (in the onPopState function):

`window.addEventListener('popstate', onPopState, true);`

I use pushState when I navigate to a new page (I navigate just by swapping which handlebars template and event handlers I am showing):

`history.pushState({page: 'home'}, 'Page Title | Home', app.client + '/home');`

I have most of the functionality working. The only problem is that if I refresh the page or type in a URL like `myapp.com/profile` in the address bar directly I get logged out and/or see an error, either a 404 if the app is deployed, or a `Cannot GET /profile` if I am running on localhost.

I think the issue is that I need to implement some kind of routing on the front end, but I am not sure how / which to use. Are there simple ways to implement this with just jQuery / JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: there is either "hash" routing (urls would have #something appended to them) or you need some server side component if you want nice looking urls with html5 routing, otherwise deeplinking won't work

Comment: Think what happens when you request GET /profile -> it asks server for resource at given location, server doesn't know what to respond with

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with hash routing.